# Загрузка библиотеки Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Пытаюсь вызвать метод `getTemplate` из класса `InitTemplate`.

Сначала, **загружаю библиотеку:**

```
$this->CI->load->library('InitTemplate', $this->posts);
```

**Затем вызываю метод:**

```
$view = $this->CI->InitTemplate->getTemplate();
```

**И получаю ошибку:**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getTemplate() on a non-object in line $this->CI->InitTemplate->getTemplate();
```

**Если сделать:**

`echo 'test';` в конструкторе `InitTemplate`, то это работает, т.е. библиотека подгружается.

Comment: Никогда не работал с CodeIgniter, но если загрузка библиотеки предполагает под собой создание объекта, то попробуйте сохранить её в переменную и вызывать оттуда getTemplate.

Comment: @andreyqin, зря ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Проверьте регистры функций.
2. СКОРЕЕ ВСЕГО: `$view` объявите ее сперва, она должна быть форматом класса.
3. ВОЗМОЖНО: я тоже работаю на CI, точно не знаю, какая у вас версия, но у него есть фитча (погуглите в user_guide вашей версии, как правильно создавать свои библиотеки), там вроде своя библиотека по правилу: 1-я буква большая, остальные маленькие, либо все маленькие (покрутите регистры).

---

**К названиям функций это тоже относится.**

Answer (score 0):

$CI - это инициализация переменной внутри библиотеки ($CI =& get_instance()), затем все объекты вызываются с помощью $CI, вместо $this. 
Сама библиотека вызывается так: $this->load->library(...);